# Passing window object from a.html to b.html via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two file
A.html

```
<a href="B.html">B</a> 
<script>
var mywindow = open("child.html","child", "height=200,width=200");
</script>
```

B.html

```
<script>
  /*want to use mywindow property .Can we serialize whole window object and pass ? */
</script>
```

When I move to b.html, can we use mywindow variable with all its window properties. So that I can still play around with child window from b.html.

Comment: have you any layout or common file where you include it?

Comment: No, its just moving to the another new file with noe common or layout file

Comment: try to make this variable as a global and you can access it anywhere .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `B.html`, you could use:

```
var win = open ('', 'child');
```

As long as you use the same window name (`child`) you used when first opening the window.